# Apple App Tracking Transparency and Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, att, apptrackingtransparency

The recent WWDC Apple launched "App Tracking Transparency framework" and will be a part of iOS 14.3:

> With iOS 14, iPadOS 14, and tvOS 14, you will need to receive the
> user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework to
> track them or access their device’s advertising identifier. Tracking
> refers to the act of linking user or device data collected from your
> app with user or device data collected from other companies’ apps,
> websites, or offline properties for targeted advertising or
> advertising

It's very vague information from Apple and Google how App Tracking Transparency will handle Google Analytics. Anyone know if ATT will affect the usage of Google Analytics in iOS14?

Comment: It depends on whether you have enabled IDFA access https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/optional-features

Comment: it seems to me that the problem is larger than IDFA availability, since Apple explains when ATT is required : "Tracking refers to the act of linking user or device data collected from your app with user or device data collected from other companies’ apps, websites, or offline properties for targeted advertising or advertising measurement purposes." https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/ . Does Google use firebase data in some way for targetting? it is not clear to me

Answer (score 1):

**From Firebase documentation:**

Analytics event logging, event reporting, and conversion measurement are unaffected, but attribution is impacted if IDFA is not accessible. To learn more about Google’s response to iOS 14, see our blog [post](https://blog.google/products/ads-commerce/preparing-developers-and-advertisers-for-policy-updates/).

You can see all affected Firebase products here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14

Comment: what is meant by `attribution is impacted` I cant understand...?

Comment: @csguy attribution is often referred to what source you attribute the install. Marketeers / Growth hackers / PMs might want to know which users came from "Facebook Ads - Campaign Cute Dogs" and compare their LTV against "Facebook - Campaign Flying Horses". IDFA makes the link between `Facebook -> App Store -> Your app` because it's the same unique device ID; without it *attribution is impacted* because Google has more difficulties finding whether a certain user installed the app after an ad (even though there are other methods like fingerprinting to achieve this, but more error-prone)

Comment: Your comment is not enough. Please explain in more detail.